# jQuery loop through JSON prints only last block

Tags: jquery, json

I have problem with looping through JSON, my example prints only last block of JSON.

JSON example:

```
[{
"date": "May 15 2015 12:00:00:000AM",
"link": "somelink1.pdf"
}, {
"date": "May 15 2015 12:00:00:000AM",
"link": "somelink2.pdf"
}
]
```

jQuery part:

```
$.getJSON("PlaceOfMyJSON.php", function(response) {
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
$('#result').html(item.link);    
});
});
```

In live JSON I have many data but this loop print only last "link" field "somelink2.pdf" in my div with id result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because you are overwriting your html again and again.

You need to update from

```
$('#result').html(item.link);
```

to

```
$('#result').append(item.link);
```

For reference - http://api.jquery.com/append/